# Calling Ansible adhoc commands/playbooks in python script

Tags: python, ansible

How to run Ansible playbooks and commands from python script

Is this suggesgted way?
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html#python-api-example

Called ansible playbook/adhoc commands runs smoothly inside python script

Answer (score 0):

Ansible doesn't recommend using that method. Quoting directly from the link you shared:

> This API is intended for internal Ansible use. Ansible may make
>   changes to this API at any time that could break backward
>   compatibility with older versions of the API. Because of this,
>   external use is not supported by Ansible.

Another option would be to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library to call your command using the command line syntax (as opposed to the API).

Comment: You mean to run ansible playbook in shell script and call that script using subprocess? subprocess has 3 options 1. Popen 2. call and 3. run. Which one will be preferred in this case? Ansible playbook runs for more than 30 min.  I want to collect output and wait. looks like call is preferred approach.

Comment: Yes, if you are waiting for the process to terminate, then `call` is the most straightforward way. Do note that `popen` is the most general function, and `call` is just a wrapper around it though.

Comment: And to answer your first question, I meant something like `subprocess.call(["ansible-playbook", "playbook.yaml", etc...])`